# Reference grouped tables with hyperlinks

Tags: tables, hyperref

I have the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\begin{document}
As seen in Table \ref{table1} and \ref{table2}.
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l | c || r }
  \hline                        
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \hline  
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 1}
\label{table1}
\begin{tabular}{ l | c || r }
  \hline                        
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \hline  
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 2}
\label{table2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have two 'tabulars' defined within a table, this a requirement for me. I'm using the `hyperref` package to have clickable links to the tables. I'm also using `\usepackage[all]{hypcap}` in the premable so that on clicking the links, the page scrolls to the top of the table instead of the caption. However, on clicking the link of Table 2, the page scrolls to the caption. I'm suspecting this is happening because I have two tables grouped together.

How could I go about this? I accept any workarounds as long as the tables would remain grouped together. I'd like to use this for figures as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `\capstart` is automatically set in `table` by `\usepackage[all]{hypcap}`. But the second `\capstart` for the second `\caption` needs to be placed manually:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\begin{document}
  As seen in Table \ref{table1} and \ref{table2}.
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ l | c || r }
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      4 & 5 & 6 \\
      7 & 8 & 9 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table 1}
    \label{table1}

    \bigskip
    \capstart
    \begin{tabular}{ l | c || r }
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      4 & 5 & 6 \\
      7 & 8 & 9 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table 2}
    \label{table2}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

(Image with `\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}` for smaller image.)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but it violates your assumption to have table within the table, yet the result is the same I suppose:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\begin{document}
As seen in Table \ref{table1} and \ref{table2}.

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l | c || r }
 \hline                        
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
 \hline  
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Table 1}
\label{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l | c || r }
  \hline                        
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \hline  
 \end{tabular}

\caption{Table 2}
\label{table2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```